# Is it possible to easily share data between an iOS app and android app?

Tags: android, ios, url-scheme

How would one share data (string/url etc) between an iPhone app and an Android app? I'm thinking a server-side solution is overkill for what I want, so my next idea was to use wifi or bluetooth to sync the iOS and Android device. Is this even possible and if so what is the best way to approach this problem?

Does anyone have any frameworks or resources that could help me? Cheers.

Comment: be more specific, what kind of data and how much?

Comment: what use case do you have for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Bluetooth is an option because of the restrictions imposed by the iOS framework.

Peer to peer synching via wifi will require one or both apps to act as a server. You'll have to decided which network protocol to use. I suspect that HTTP will be the easiest to implement but it may not be well suited to your requirements.

You then have the problem of discovering peers on the local network. This is relatively straight forward with iOS to iOS devices because of Bonjour. I don't know if there are any bonjour frameworks for Andriod.

Personally I'd try to make it work with a standard web server.

Answer (score 1):

The server side solution will be the easier one for your users (and for you, it's way easier to implement), because you can then synchronize your apps in background without asking your users to activate bluetooth or wifi on two devices simultaneously.

Furthermore, I don't know exactly how your apps work, but your users will always need to carry these two devices. If not, they will be stuck. If the data is stored on a server, however, they will just need to click on a button which is more user-friendly.